# Python - how do I add a string to a list item and return the modified list item

Tags: python-3.x

My block of code is supposed to iterate through a list, find items that meet a condition of starting with "/", and then modify that specific list item.

```
paths = ["/home.html", "index.html", "/file.html"]

for i in paths:
   if i.startswith("/"):
     i == ("https://www.me.com", i)
   else:
     pass

print(paths)
```

or you can see here: [a link](https://repl.it/repls/TepidLightgrayTag)

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing same variable which you have defined. Iterating over list won't change that list element.

This code will help you :

```
paths = ["/home.html", "index.html", "/file.html"]
new_paths = []
for i in paths:
   if i.startswith("/"):
     i = "https://www.me.com" + str(i)
     new_paths.append(i)
   else:
     pass

print(new_paths)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to interate over the number of elements, rather than the elements themselves.  This gives you a way to change the element during the loop

```
paths = ["/home.html", "index.html", "/file.html"]
for i in range(len(paths)):
     if (paths[i].startswith("/")):
         paths[i] = "https://www.me.com" + paths[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate` to get the current position of the list element and modify it. Note that you don't need the else condition.

```
paths = ["/home.html", "index.html", "/file.html"]

for idx, val in enumerate(paths):
    if val.startswith("/"):
      paths[idx] = "https://www.me.com" + str(val)

print(paths)
```

This prints on my machine

```
['https://www.me.com/home.html', 'index.html', 'https://www.me.com/file.html']
```